# Notification for user group

Tags: php

I'm working on a event manager and I would like to create a notification system for a group of users.
When an admin creates a new event then php create a notification inside mysql with status 0 if not read and then it changes to status 1 if read.

The problem is that I'm using the group id instead of the user id, and when the first logged user click on the notification it updates the notification status so other users are not viewing the notification. Maybe inserting a row for each user into the database can solve this problem? do I need to use an array of user's ids?

This is what i've done so far:

```
session_start();

// admin id 
$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

include('../../../config/database.php');

$event_title = $_POST['titleevent'];
$event_color = $_POST['eventcolor'];
$event_start = $_POST['startevent'];
$new_start_date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($event_start));
$event_end = $_POST['endevent'];
$new_end_date = date('Y-m-d 23:59:00', strtotime($event_end));
$event_group = $_POST['usergroup'];
$event_description = $_POST['eventdescription'];

    if ($create_event = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO user_events (event_title, event_description, event_start, event_end, event_color, event_group)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" )) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($create_event, 'sssssi', $event_title, $event_description, $new_start_date, $new_end_date, $event_color, $event_group);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($create_event);

        // get event id
        $event_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

        $event_start_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($new_start_date));
        $notification = "Nuovo evento <span class='text-warning'><strong>$event_title</strong></span> inizia il $event_start_date";
        $notification_status = "0";
        $notification_category= "events";

        $event_notification = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO event_notifications (e_notification_sent_by, e_notification_sent_to, e_notification_message, e_notification_time, e_notification_status, e_notification_category, e_notification_category_id) VALUES(?,?,?,now(),?,?,?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($event_notification, 'iisisi', $userid, $event_group, $notification, $notification_status, $notification_category, $event_id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($event_notification);
        mysqli_stmt_close($event_notification);


     echo "event created";

    mysqli_stmt_close($create_event);


    }else{

        echo "Ops, error";

    }
```

Many thanks for you help

UPDATE i've managed to make it working using an array and foreach in this way:

```
$event_start_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($new_start_date));
        $notification = "Nuovo evento <span class='text-warning'><strong>$event_title</strong></span> inizia il $event_start_date";
        $notification_status = "0";
        $notification_category= "events";


        $sql = "SELECT user_join_id FROM user_group_join WHERE group_join_id='$event_group'";

        $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        $datas= array();

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

            $datas[]= $row;

            }

        }

        foreach($datas as $data) {

        $id_cliente = $data['user_join_id'];

        $event_notification = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO user_notifications (notification_sent_by, notification_sent_to, notification_message, notification_time, notification_status, notification_category, notification_category_id) VALUES(?,?,?,now(),?,?,?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($event_notification, 'iisisi', $userid, $id_cliente, $notification, $notification_status, $notification_category, $event_id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($event_notification);
        mysqli_stmt_close($event_notification);

        }
```

**Now the question is how can i can i convert it with a prepared statement? And also it looks like i'm going to use a lot of server resources querying  the database for each user id, is there any way to optimize the foreach loop?**

Many thanks

Comment: You'd (probably) need to use UPDATE in order to "update" a said row for a boolean `0|1`, if that's what the question is about.

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii- thanks for your answer i run the update with ajax on click event. What I need to do is get all the user's id that belong to a specific group maybe with an array and then create a row in the database for each user so maybe I could use the array of id instead of $event_group in the event_notification query.

Comment: Run a SELECT with a `WHERE` clause, using their respective columns.

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't work if i have more than one user in the group :(

Comment: it's hard to say why it's not working here for you, since I don't know what the query for it looks like. If you're going a GROUP BY, or LIMIT 1, or not using the function, then that could be one or more reasons why.

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii- sorry to trouble you again, I've managed to do solve the problem using array and foreach, i've edited my question. Now the problem is how to use a prepared statement. Many thanks